# Why use async if all you do is wait for it to complete?

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I came across some C++ code like this:

```
aThread->async( [=]() {
    // ... do stuff ...
} ).wait();
```

What is the point of running code on a thread if all you do is wait for it to complete?   Why not replace the code above with just:

```
// ... do stuff ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure about c++ but in c# that wouldn't be guaranteed to run on a different thread. The CLR could decide to do a number of things with it that might be more optimal.

Comment: So what is `aThread`? This isn't `std::async` (which is a non-member function), so we can't answer without knowing exactly what this non-standard function does. Perhaps this is intended to run the code on one thread in particular, to synchronise it with other operations on that thread.

Comment: So what is the type of `aThread`? And what does this `async` method do?

Comment: threads are so overused :(  but this one does take the cake

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree. Creating a thread and then just waiting for the thread to finish serves very little purpose.

Comment: Sounds like someone don't know what they were doing. Unless there's something "interesting" in ... do stuff ... that makes sense to run in a separate thread for some reason...

Comment: Although this looks more like it's running the code on an existing thread, rather than creating one, which would make rather more sense. It's hard to guess from the information provided, though.

Comment: Wouldn't it be hard to tell without knowing what exactly `aThread` is and what the `async` method does? It could launch a parallel computation with 100 threads for all we know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe aThread own ressources which are necessary to do the work and you can't use them or create them in the caller thread.